# Poor aqueous solubility of chloroazodin

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility

Below is the structure of [chloroazodin](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/chloroazodin):

[image: chloroazodin structure]

Why is chloroazodin [poorly soluble in water](https://books.google.com/books?id=3f-kPJ17_TYC&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=solubility%20of%20chloroazodin&source=bl&ots=KmFjEu7QLZ&sig=A9vsrvFJnjs5Hcwqq2Ak_9pWFr8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ3PeQq__LAhXjlIMKHSdACLEQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=solubility%20of%20chloroazodin&f=false)? It has multiple amine and imine nitrogens, all of which appear to be available for hydrogen bonding, and thus it seems it should exhibit high aqueous solubility.

Chloroazodin is mostly insoluble in water and organic solvents. I can't explain this character which is in contrast with its structure.

Comment: Welcome to Chem.SE! Thanks for posting your question here. Please take a look at my edits to your question, and feel free to edit/change anything that you don't like.  If you haven't already, please check out the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) pages for more information. Enjoy!

Comment: thanks.but chloroazodin is mostly insoluble in water and organic solvents.i cant explain this character which is in contrast with its structure.

Comment: It may be surprising, but seems to be standard tendency for compounds that they may be **too** strongly hydrogen bonded to be easily dissolved in water.

Comment: @Mithoron, interesting and maybe pretty relevant to the (now very old) question.  Can you give any examples?

Comment: Note that your link calls it a "chlorine releasing antiseptic". It doesn't give a mechanism or show the products remaining after releasing chlorine, but if this happens rapidly in aqueous solution then the compound that doesn't dissolve may be that/those product(s).  Does this seem reasonable based on what you know or have seen about this?

Comment: @airhuff Azodicarboxamide https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Azodicarboxamide#section=Flash-Point

Comment: Care to come to chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table